# Calling reset with object?

Tags: php

I was surprised to see the [reset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) function work on objects.

```
<?php

class C {
  private $a = 'a';
  protected $b = 'b';
  public $c = 'c';
}

$c = new C;
echo reset($c); // a
```

It looks like if reset receives an object it first casts it to an array?
This is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation.
Is this an implementation detail?

Comment: Well, it's defined as `reset ( array &$array ) `, so it's mentioned *somehow*.

Comment: Roughly speaking PHP willl [type juggle](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) the parameters for built-in functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object is not cast into an array. It is native feature of the `reset()` function to accept an object and use it's property table (although this functionality is not really documented anywhere)

But if you check out [the implementation](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L1189) of `reset()` in the PHP interpreter you see it defines the function parameter as a `Z_PARAM_ARRAY_OR_OBJECT_HT_EX` which according to the internal docs means (emphasis mine):

> #### Z_PARAM_ARRAY_OR_OBJECT_HT
>
> Specify a parameter that should parsed as either an array or an object into a HashTable. **If the argument is an object, then the object's property table will be used**.....
>
> — [phpinternals](https://phpinternals.net/docs/z_param_array_or_object_ht)

Other functions that uses this type of parameter include  `current()` and `next()` which may also accept an object as input.